# Changing a variable with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How i change the var daynames font-size and color, using css?

```
var monthNames = [ "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro" ]; 

var dayNames= ["Domingo","Segunda-feira","Terça-feira","Quarta-feira","Quinta-feira","Sexta-feira","Sabado"]
var newDate = new Date();

newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());

$('#Date').html(dayNames[newDate.getDay()] + "<br>" + newDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to add font-size and color.

```
 $('#Date').html("<span style='font-size:28px; color:#ffffff;'>" + dayNames[newDate.getDay()] + "</span><br>" + newDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Glad i could help :), accept the answer, which works for you the best. So it may help others

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var dayNames= ["<p style='color:blue;font-size:10px;'>Domingo</p>",
               "<p style='color:red;font-size:10px;'>Segunda-feira</p>",
               "<p style='color:gray;font-size:10px;'>Terça-feira</p>",
               "<p style='color:yellow;font-size:10px;'>Quarta-feira</p>",
              "<p style='color:red;font-size:10px;'>Quinta-feira</p>",
               "<p style='color:red;font-size:10px;'>Sexta-feira</p>",
              "<p style='color:red;font-size:10px;'>Sabado</p>"]
```

or

```
 var style="<p style='color:red;font-size:10px;'>";

 var dayNames= [style+"Domingo</p>",
               style+"Segunda-feira</p>",
               style+"Terça-feira</p>",
               style+"Quarta-feira</p>",
              style+"Quinta-feira</p>",
               style+"Sexta-feira</p>",
              style+"Sabado</p>"]
```

Comment: this is not a good solution, you are mixing HTML with the DATA, the way you had it initially was much better.

Comment: @mauriatti heres an example of why you want to separate your data from your html. I was easily able to create something reusable http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/h8Jh2/6/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/h8Jh2/)

```
$('.date').html(
    '<span class="dayname">' +dayNames[newDate.getDay()] + '</span><br />' + 
    '<span class="day">' + newDate.getDate() + '</span> ' +
    '<span class="month">' + monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + '</span> ' +
    '<span class="year">' + newDate.getFullYear() + '</span>'
);
```

then you can control the styling like this

```
.dayname {
    color: orange;
    font-size: 32px;
}
.day {
    color: red;
}
.month {
    color: green;
}
.year {
    color: blue;
}
```

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here, but its usually smart to avoid `inline styles`, unless it needs to be dynamic.